# HP ProLiant Shared ILO port do not answer to host

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, rhel6, ilo

I have a HP-proliant dl160 gen 9 with an iLO 4 configured with a Shared Network Port - LOM on port 1, the port is see as eth0 by Red Hat Enterprise linux 6.5 and used as a bridged port.

The port is connected to a switch, **I can ping/http/IPMI the iLO from another computer connected to the switch, but I cannot from the host computer.**
With tcpdump I can see the ARP packets going out of eth0, but no answer coming back.

I already found this answer : https://serverfault.com/a/710436 so I am wondering if I have a configuration issue, or if I am trying to do something impossible ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @vonbrand : The host is supposed to monitor itself with ipmitool, it worked perfectly with a gen8 and a dedicated port, but I am stuck with a shared port.

Comment: @willll That's a strange use case. You don't want to use the HP agents?

Comment: @ewwhite : do you mean HP SMH ? The system is supposed to shutdown itself using the iLO, but as far I understood the host does not communicate directly with the iLO.

Comment: No, I mean, HP's management agents. You can also issue commands to the ILO. Why does the server have to shut itself down with the ILO? What *are* you doing?

Comment: @ewwhite : It is a redundancy solution using DRDB, for maintenance purpose you are able to shutdown the master/slave. So the master is able to "kill itself".

Comment: So you're just trying to fence using ILO? Best option is to add a NIC.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work. It's one of the downsides to using a shared ILO port.

Comment: thank you, do you have any documentation related to this point ?

Comment: No. It just doesn't work.

Comment: This is a pretty frustrating and opaque roadblock

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use a router to redirect routers port to ILO ssh port. I am in the same situation and i just nmapped a port on a router, made a redirect to the ILOs ssh. Its working perfectly. I am automating higher fan speed @ night and lower @ day with modified ILOs firmware.